# Strongswan client on local router - clients cannot access network at all?

Tags: iptables, routing, strongswan

I've setup strongswan on the router (Debian Stretch) and strongswan configuration works well, but only for connections issued from router.

However, once the tunnel goes up clients behind the router (192.168.10.0/24 from below) lose all connectivity completely. Meaning they are no longer able to access Internet, nor they get routed through tunnel, nor even ping/telnet/ssh the router itself (192.168.10.1). The goal is for those clients to be able to access Internet by tunneling all their traffic via ASA.

The setup is as follows:

network (the clients from left LAN should have their traffic go through tunnel and get internet access behind right LAN):

```
+---------------+ +------------------+         +-----------+ +------------+
|   local LAN   | |    router        |         | Cisco ASA | | local LAN  |
|192.168.10.0/24+-+eth0:192.168.1.1  +-Network-+  1.1.1.1  +-+10.10.0.0/24+-Internet
|               | |eth1:192.168.10.1 |         |           | |            |
+---------------+ +------------------+         +-----------+ +------------+
```

ipsec.conf:

```
config setup

conn tunnel
    authby=psk
    auto=start
    keyingtries=%forever
    rekey=yes

    dpdaction=restart
    closeaction=restart

    keyexchange=ikev1
    aggressive=yes
    fragmentation=yes

    ike=aes-sha-modp1024
    esp=aes-sha
    type=tunnel
    forceencaps=yes

    left=%defaultroute
    leftid=@GroupName
    leftauth=psk
    leftauth2=xauth
    xauth_identity=user.name
    leftsourceip=%config

    right=1.1.1.1
    rightauth=psk
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
```

iptables-save:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [762:57704]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [457:52596]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -s 192.168.10.0/24 ! -d 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:984]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:984]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:104]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Comment: I'd start by checking tcpdump on the debian machine. You can confirm which packets arrive and leave, when and to whom.

Comment: @Zip good point. Will check it that for sure after the weekend